# Why do I get phone storage is getting low when I've un-installed almost all apps?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage

I keep getting "phone storage is getting low" constantly even though I've removed almost all the apps I've installed. Is there a way to look in the phone storage to see what are the contents?

Google Talk and Facebook fail to function because of this.

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc running Android 2.3 (Build 4.0.2.A.0.62)

Comment: Install Disk Usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you haven't removed only the small apps that doesn't take significant space.

Go to settings -> Apps -> Select "All" on apps tab -> Click menu and click sort by size.

You'll see the apps sorted by the size it takes on your phone. Check if the top apps in this list are taking most of your space.

Comment: I was able to delete the data for a few unused apps that were collecting geo data and get back about 100MB of space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go see my answer to that similar question:
[Space problem in Samsung Galaxy Pocket GT-S5300](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30620/space-problem-in-samsung-galaxy-pocket-gt-s5300)

It solved all my problem. Samsung told me to reset my device to factory firmware. I did not want to have to reinstall everything and now I know it will always happen after a while. Follow the procedure at that link and you might have to do it once or twice per year to keep it clean but you will not have to reset your device.